# Preview Crashes Repeatedly on Yosemite 10.10.1

Tags: macos, preview

I installed Yosemite 10.10.1 about a week ago. Preview crashes *all the time* whenever I try to perform a search on certain documents. Unfortunately, I can't upload this document because of copyright infringement issues. I never experienced this before (in the many times I searched) with Mavericks but it has happened quite often with Yosemite.

1. Is anyone else experiencing the same problem?
2. What is a possible solution?

Kind regards,

polarise

I would happily securely send the actual document to an Apple employee to reproduce the fault.

Comment: When in doubt, reinstalling the OS is a classic troubleshooting measure.

When still in doubt, maybe check Activity Monitor to see if, rather than it being an actual bug, you're just running low enough on CPU/RAM for invoking the search feature to push you over the edge?

Comment: Reinstalling the OS because a search fails in one app seems like overkill to me. I also can't bring myself to believe that I'm pushing my Mac over the edge.

Comment: If there's a block of time when you'll be leaving your computer unattended for a while, you've got nothing to lose. Maybe you could let a reinstall run overnight. And you've also got nothing to lose just by cracking open Activity Monitor. Who knows, you may even be able to pinpoint the offending process.

Comment: You could also see if Disk Utility has anything to say about the state of your disk or its permissions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad that you hesitated to reinstall the OS because of problems with one app. I saw this on 10.10.1 and actually it has gotten worse on 10.10.2. It's not search per se, but just opening certain kinds of PDFs that have been cropped using a Java-based tool called "Briss" (which converts 2-up scans to 1-up).

I think that this is a Yosemite bug that hasn't been fixed yet. PDFPen from Smile Software does not crash when viewing these PDFs.